# Why my application crash on ubuntu-touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I want to try to create un application for ubuntu-touch with QML !

I was created a simple application :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import "components"


/*!
    \brief MainView with a Label and Button elements.
*/
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

MainView {
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    objectName: "mainView"

    // Note! applicationName needs to match the "name" field of the click manifest
    applicationName: "com.ubuntu.developer.z-admin-angels-gmail-com.oweMe"

    /*
     This property enables the application to change orientation
     when the device is rotated. The default is false.
    */
    automaticOrientation: true

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("oweMe")

        Column {
            anchors.rightMargin: 8
            anchors.bottomMargin: 8
            anchors.leftMargin: 24
            anchors.topMargin: 24
            spacing: units.gu(1)
            anchors {
                margins: units.gu(2)
                fill: parent
            }

            Row {
                id: gridButton
                x: 218
                y: 30
                width: 541
                height: 65

                Button {
                    objectName: "addDebpt"
                    text: i18n.tr("add debpt")
                    color: UbuntuColors.midAubergine
                    onClicked: {
                        var component = Qt.createComponent("qml/MyQmlFile.qml");
                                        if (component.status == Component.Ready)
                                            component.createObject(label1, {"x": 100, "y": 100});

                    }
                }

                /*Button {
                    width: 153
                    objectName: "addCommunBuy"
                    text: i18n.tr("add commun Buy")
                    color: UbuntuColors.lightAubergine
                    onClicked: {

                    }
                }*/

                Button {
                    width: 153
                    objectName: "removeDebpt"
                    text: i18n.tr("remove debpt")
                    color: UbuntuColors.lightAubergine
                    onClicked: {

                    }
                }

            } // ButtonGRID
        }

        GridLayout {
            id: gridForm
            x: 42
            y: 92
            width: 622
            height: 340

            Label {
                id: label1
                x: 227
                y: 218
                width: 272
                height: 89
                text: qsTr("Open QML HERE")
                font.pointSize: 21
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
            }
        }
    } // grid Content
}
```

When I lunch my application trought ubuntu i386 emulator, the application crash ...
Or when I run it with desktop I have no problem

Application output :

```
Executing: /tmp/com.ubuntu.developer.username.oweme_0.1_all.click Launcher PID: 4502 AppId: com.ubuntu.developer.username.oweme_oweMe_0.1 Architecture: all

Transaction:    Installing files Status:    Waiting in queue Status:    Starting Status:    Finished Transaction:   Installing files Status:    Waiting in queue Status:    Waiting for authentication Status:  Waiting in queue Status:    Starting Status:    Finished Results: Installed    com.ubuntu.developer.username.oweme-0.1.all (installed:click,removable=1,app_name=oweMe) Application installed, executing Registering hooks Start Application Application started: 4572



Received a failed event The Application exited, cleaning up Transaction:    Removing Status:    Waiting in queue Status:    Starting Status:    Finished Transaction:   Removing Status:    Waiting in queue Status:    Waiting for authentication Status:  Waiting in queue Status:    Starting Status:    Finished Results:
```

and general output :

> [15:38:15] ii click-reviewers-tools 0.8-0~214~ubuntu14.04.1

and my compilation output :

```
16:28:56: Running steps for project oweMe...
sending incremental file list
deleting qtc_device_debughelper.py
./
oweMe.desktop
oweMe.json

sent 682 bytes  received 89 bytes  1.54K bytes/sec
total size is 46.47K  speedup is 60.27
16:28:56: The process "/usr/bin/rsync" exited normally.
WARNING:root:Ignoring missing framework "ubuntu-sdk-14.10-dev2"
Successfully built package in './com.ubuntu.developer.username.oweme_0.1_all.click'.
16:28:56: The process "/usr/bin/click" exited normally.
16:28:56: The click package has been created in /home/morgan/build-oweMe-ubuntui386_GCC_i386_ubuntu_sdk_14_10_utopic-default
16:28:56: Connecting to device...
16:28:57: Uploading file '/home/morgan/build-oweMe-ubuntui386_GCC_i386_ubuntu_sdk_14_10_utopic-default/com.ubuntu.developer.username.oweme_0.1_all.click'...
16:28:57: Uploading file '/usr/share/qtcreator/ubuntu/scripts/qtc_device_applaunch.py'...
16:28:57: All files successfully deployed.
16:28:57: Deploy step finished.
16:28:57: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem !

It's crash because I use

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
```

without that, it's work well

Comment: Could you mark the question as solved by choosing your answer?